# How to place text on top of two table cells?

Tags: css, html-table

Lets say we have this table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="50px">Text crossing two td´s</td>
    <td width="50px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can the text be on top of the two td´s and follow the size of the tr?

https://jsfiddle.net/roj7w1t4/

Is it possible?

**EDIT**
I need the borders to stay visible. Therefore i cannot use colspan!
Is it possible to create a span and put it over the td´s?

To make more sense what i am trying to do.. this is a small example of my application: [What printable element is better to use than linear-gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274093/what-printable-element-is-better-to-use-than-linear-gradient)

**THE ELEMENT**

```
<div class="elementsDiv ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="29065-1_105" data-weight="938" data-nr="105" style="width: 159.5px; height: 20px; position: absolute; left: 108px; top: 27.1875px;"><table style="height: 100%;"><tbody><tr style="border 1px solid black;"><td style="width: 34.2px; border-right: 1px dotted black;">105</td><td style="width: 91px; border-right: 1px dotted black;"></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: You can make the text go outside the one `td`, but I don't think you can make it follow the width of the second `td` is that is what you want. Is altering the HTML markup an option? You could use `colspan="2"` on the `td`.

Comment: use `colspan=2`

Comment: Use `colspan` https://jsfiddle.net/roj7w1t4/1/ ??

Comment: @BjörnC, You mean which border?

Comment: Can't say I can see any reason to do this. In HTML with tablatur layout, this makes no sense. Why would you want the text inside a column, but also break it at the same time? An alternative approach could be to draw the border between the two columns with a "hack" instead.

Comment: Which part from @Maddy 's answer doesn't fulfill what you need? The borders are visible

Comment: @OptimusCrime The story why i need it is complex. I need text optop/over the table tr/td. I need this to be printable in all browsers.. therfore i use a table and not a img or linear-gradient as i used before.

Comment: @LorekBryanson I need a text OVER the borders.. from two td´s.

Comment: @LorekBryanson Yes, i used linear-gradient.. and it works well in the browser.. but is not always printed.. Therefore i switched to table and borders...

Comment: I simply belive this is impossible to do with just CSS.

Comment: @OptimusCrime But isn´t there a way.. to add a span.. and change the z-index... and place it on top of the table/tr with margins and positions?

Comment: @BjörnC There are ways to do something resembling what you want, but there are a few differences: 1) the text in your example in inside the `td`, not outside the table. 2) you want the text to adhere to the width of the entire table, without a predefined width this is impossible, as you can not reuse widths of other (known sized) objects. But if you have a container around the table, and you can place the text outside the table, then there are ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: If Tyler Bean´s answer is printable.. i think it might work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can image doing this is placing an element outside the table and having a container around the table and the element. Then placing the element using position absolute on top of the table.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
table {
  width: 200px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 40px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

th {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Monthly Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50px">This text should cross two td´s</td>
    <td width="50px"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**You can include  the border will be visible.
All the best. For any query please comment.**

Comment: Sorry, this question is more complex.. You need to read all the comments and added content to the question. I need the text to be ontop/over/crossing the borders between the td´s

Answer (score 1):

How about changing your html layout? Try to use `after` pseudo element and `position:absolute`. This technique saves me in a lot of situation and it's very strong, I think.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
}

div:after {
  background: green;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
This text should cross two td´s
</div>
```

Comment: Now this seems like what i want! Thank you, i will experiment with it!